# How to make a Clojure go loop run forever

Tags: clojure

I want to use Clojure core.async to write an application that sits in a loop polling a service, but my attempts so far terminate unexpectedly.

When I run this program it prints the message then exits:

```
(defn -main
  []
  (println "Running forever...?")
  (async/go-loop [n 0]
                 (prn n)
                 (async/<!! (async/timeout 1000))
                 (recur (inc n))))
```

I would like the program to run forever (until the JVM process is killed).

What is the accepted way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main thread is what will keep the JVM process running (it won't care about the threads in the `go` pool).

Keep it running by blocking on the main thread. e.g.

```
(defn -main
  []
  (println "Running forever...?")
  (async/<!! (async/go-loop [n 0]
                 (prn n)
                 (async/<! (async/timeout 1000))
                 (recur (inc n)))))
```

Note: you shouldn't use `<!!` inside of a `go` block. You should instead use `<!`.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! It even exits nicely if the go-block exits.

Answer (score 1):

How many ways are there to block the main thread......?

```
(defn -main []
  (println "Running forever...?")

  ; go-loop runs forever in another (daemon) thread
  (async/go-loop [n 0]
                 (prn n)
                 (async/<!! (async/timeout 1000))
                 (recur (inc n))

  ; hang the main thread
  (Thread/sleep 111222333444))  ; long enough....
```

(or you could use `Long/MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: blast! it was you that created the "year 5592-03-22T22:38:16.661Z" bug! History will remember this!

Comment: Actually, 111 billion `milliseconds` is a duration of only about 3.5 years (not as long as I was originally guessing!). Still, probably long enough to outlast a JVM restart.    :)

Comment: `Long/MAX_VALUE` however, will create "the year 292,469,208 bug" (`(-> Long/MAX_VALUE (/ 1000 60 60 24 365) (- 2000) int)`)